# Meaning of MAC terminal command prompt

Tags: mac, terminal

I was wondering if anyone could explain the meaning the command below in mac terminal:

dhcp-74-148:~

Noticed it for the first time today and just wondering what it meant.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is called command prompt.

`dhcp-74-148` is you hostname that you received from dhcp server.

`~` is where you currently are (which directory) - tilda means you are in your home folder, /Users/[username]

`:` just separates hostname from current directory.

You can change format of command prompt by changing $PS1 variable.
And - if you're interested - check out some bash shell tutorial for more information.

Comment: thanks for that answer. I"ll read more about the shell. I just noticed that command for the first time when I opened the terminal today-I've used the terminal before but it was a different command that was there. Still trying to figure out exactly what was there previously.

Comment: You should be able to change it going to System Preferences > Sharing > Computer Name. It will also be name of your machine others will see if you will share some files or use AirDrop.

Comment: As for changing the prompt - if - for example - you do export PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\t \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h \[\033[01;34m\]\w $\[\033[00m\]', you will have nice green/blue prompt with username and time :)

Comment: Thanks so much-sry I don't have enough points to +ve rep you. Many thanks. I've figured what was there previously.